# How to select SQL results grouped by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select data from following table group by date

```
date        btype       amount
1-2-2017    income      1000
1-2-2017    income      200
1-2-2017    Expense     100
1-2-2017    Expense     200

2-2-2017    income      1000
2-2-2017    income      500
2-2-2017    Expense     1000

3-2-2017    income      2000
3-2-2017    Expense     500
```

So my result should look like this.

```
date        Income      Expense
1-2-2017    1200        300
2-2-2017    1500        1000
3-2-2017    2000        500
```

Will some body guide me to how to write SQL query to achieve this behavior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly straight forward SQL that you should be able to figure out yourself with a bit of google:

```
select date
      ,sum(if(btype = 'income', amount, 0)) as Income
      ,sum(if(btype = 'expense', amount, 0)) as Expense
from table
group by date
```

Answer (score 1):

After creating a test table, I have inserted some records, and then I used this query:

```
select date_ as Date_Time, btype, sum(amount) as amount
 from test
 group by date_ , btype
```

Comment: Please just add the scripts and results to your question as text.  If you need to format your results, go to https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ and paste in your SSMS output.

Comment: Please don't post images.

Answer (score 1):

Another method

```
select date
      ,sum(case when btype = 'income' then amount else 0 end) as Income
      ,sum(case when btype = 'expense' then amount else 0 end) as Expense
from table
group by date
```